# Inserted Data into a table is not showing up when selected in oracle

Tags: oracle

I've inserted a row in a table in oracle using SQL Developer and committed too. But when selected the data it is not showing up. Did I go wrong somewhere ?

Below is the how I inserted and selected.

```
insert into table1 (seqn,pname,city,country,irank,icode,idate,imatch)
values('1234','ABCD','NY','USA','1','XYZ',sysdate,'9999');
```

The output I get is `1 rows inserted` and then I `commit;`.
Now when I do select the data, nothing is showing up.
`select count(*) from table1;` is fecthing me `0 rows`.

Please help me out with where I am going wrong.

**Note:** All are of datatype `varchar2()` and the date is of `DATE` datatype. I've other columns in the table which can accept `NULL` data.

Comment: The `insert` and `commit` you describe should have placed the row in the table.  There are a number of unusual but possible explanations: for example, another process could be deleting the row quickly.  There are many more possibilities if `TABLE1` is, in fact, a view instead of a table.  Are you positive it is a table?  I suggest you create a new table, insert into it, commit, and see if you see the records -- just to make sure you are doing it right.

Comment: Also, if it is a table, did you create it yourself?  There could be a VPD (virtual private database) policy on the table that preventing you from reading the records in it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I've now created `TABLE2` with similar table structure and inserted data into it where I could see the data while selecting from `TABLE2`. But I'm sure no other process is deleting the inserted record from `TABLE1`. I really wonder why the result is showing `1 rows inserted` and I couldn't see any data ? Please help.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, this table is not created by me. But I've `SELECT` `INSERT` `UPDATE` `DELETE` permissions on the table. I have no idea on what this VPD is.

Comment: First, do a `SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='TABLE1'` and see the object's type.  Is it a table or a view?  Second, do a `SELECT * FROM DBA_POLICIES WHERE OBJECT_NAME='TABLE1'` to see if there are any VPD policies on that table.  If the 1st query indicates `TABLE1` is a view, look at the query for the view and see if it would return the row you inserted.  If the 2nd query indicates `TABLE1` has VPD policies, look at the value of `DBA_POLICIES.FUNCTION` for that policy.  That will be a PL/SQL package function that will return an extra WHERE clause that is probably hiding your rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself and wondering how I missed that silly thing. There is a trigger enabled on the table such that whenever I insert the data in TABLE1, the trigger moves it to another table and deletes the data from TABLE1.

**Note**: I figured it long back but posting it now just in case if someone else is missing this thing and looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Take care to insert into the* **CORRECT SCHEME**!!!

In my case I was inserting table in another scheme:

```
insert into table1 -- this inserts into some default scheme


insert into correct_scheme.table1 -- this inserts into the correct scheme
```